# Which modes are excited when a drum is struck?

Tags: acoustics

I've been searching quite extensively for an answer to this question but I cannot find anything definitive. The most I can see is that "one or several" modes become excited, but this is never parameterized by any relevant factors. I imagine it depends on the location of the strike and the force applied. I do not need an exact formula, but I would appreciate some intuition here.

I have seen several videos now of the individual modes of a circular membrane being excited by oscillators at targeted frequencies. But when the drum is actually struck, does the membrane vibrate in some superposition of these modes? Are all possible modes - all infinitely many - excited simultaneously, just with all higher modes having infinitesimal amplitude? Or is there some finite fixed limit of the number of excited modes depending on say the force of the impact? (Further, I imagine if you strike it hard enough, the material will break, so if this is the case then some higher modes would maybe never become excited, but perhaps we can gloss over such details.)

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? Is it a bad question?

Comment: probably because this seems to be answerable by a quick google search.

Comment: @Martin I'm not sure that's the case - or at least I can't find anything that answers it definitively. All I can find is the information I included: that the fundamental mode is mainly excited but other (unspecified and unquantified) modes become excited too. Since it's quick for you, can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I see some people say "one or several" modes become excited. How many is several? Could it be infinitely many?

Comment: I imagine that the "how many" answer depends on the actual force applied to the drum head and how tight it is wound. Without any real parameters, we're likely just guessing here.

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron if you are getting downvoted because the question seems to be answerable by a quick search, editing the question to say that you did such a search and didn't find results would help prevent downvotes.

Comment: @KyleKanos: That is *exactly* what I'm asking. What is the number of modes as a function of all relevant parameters?

Answer (score 2):

The functions which describe the vibrating modes of a circular drum are the Bessel functions of the first kind $J_n$, they form a complete set so you can express any function as a series of Bessel functions (Fourier-Bessel Series), they also satisfy an orthogonality relation, then knowing the function $F$ which approximates the applied force you can calculate the coefficients in the series projecting $F$ onto $J_n$. The magnitude of the coefficients will tell you which modes are more easily excited.

Answer (score 0):

The question 
mixes membranes and drums. 
Hitting a membrane is different from a drum, because drums 
have (more or less, depending on type of drum) a strongly
coupled air volume controlling the vibration of the drum. 
A turkish kettle drum will have almost no higher modes, 
whereas those membranes as used by Inuit people will 
show Bessel modes.